# How do i calculate total without manually inputting it?

Tags: c++

I have identified that the problem is when calculating total. When i key in the value manually as 281 it works fine but i do not want to do that. So how can i solve this issue? Please help thank you. I have a added a comment in the line where the problem is.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int mark[5] = {30, 50, 66, 90, 45};
    double total;
    
// THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS    
    total = total + mark[5];
    
    
    double average = total / 5;
    int lowest = mark[0], highest = mark[0];

    
    for(int i=1; i<=4; i++){
        if(mark[i]<lowest)
            lowest = mark[i];
        if(mark[i]>highest)
            highest = mark[i];
    }
    
     cout << endl;
    
    
    cout << "Average mark: " << average << endl;
    cout << "Highest mark: " << highest << endl;
    cout << "Lowest mark: " << lowest <<endl;
    
    
    cout << endl;
    
//display all values that are higher than the calculated average values.    
    for (int i = 0; i<=4; i++){
        if (mark[i] > average)
            cout << mark[i] << " ";
    }
        
             
            
    cout << endl;
    
    
// count the number of marks which is less than 50  
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0; i<=4; i++){
        if(mark[i] < 50)
            count++;
    }         
    cout << "Elements which are <50: " << count; 
    
    cout << endl;
    cout << "all integers: ";

//Displaying all the integers in the array.         
    for (int i = 0; i <=4; ++i) {
        cout << mark[i] << "  ";   
    }
            
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `mark[5]` is the 6th element or `mark`, which is going to be a problem since that doesn't exist.

Comment: `double total;` does not initialize total to 0.

Comment: `const auto total = std::accumulate(std::begin(mark), std::end(mark), 0);`

Comment: `const auto [minIt, maxIt] = std::minmax_element(std::begin(mark), std::end(mark)); const auto lowest = *minIt; const auto highest = *maxIt;`.

Comment: Did you expect `total + mark[5]` to add all the elements of `mark` to `total`? That's not how C++ works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`total = total + mark[5];`

That is wrong.  `mark` subscripts range from 0 through 4 inclusive.  You accessed an out of range index which results in undefined behavior.

`double average = total / 5;`

At this point, the only line that set a value for `total` is the wrong one above.  If you removed that wrong line, `total` is undefined, stack garbage.  That's your problem.  You never actually found the total.

You should use [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) to do this in one simple call.

Then, use range-based `for` loops to go through the data again:

```
//Displaying all the integers in the array.         
    for (const auto val : mark) {
        cout << val << "  ";   
    }
```

## General advice:

Don't write `using namespace std;`.

Don't declare variables until they are needed, and *initialize* them.

Know what's available for you in the standard algorithms etc.  (⭐[hint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)⭐)

## rewrite

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

using std::begin; using std::end;
using std::cout;

int main() 
{
    constexpr int mark[] = {30, 50, 66, 90, 45};
    
    const auto total = std::accumulate (begin(mark),end(mark),0);
    const auto average = double(total)/std::size(mark);
    
    const auto [lowest_it, highest_it] = std::minmax_element (begin(mark),end(mark));
    const auto lowest= *lowest_it;
    const auto highest= *highest_it;
    
    
    cout << "\nAverage mark: " << average
         << "\nHighest mark: " << highest
         << "\nLowest mark: " << lowest << "\n\n";
    
    
//display all values that are higher than the calculated average values.    
    for (const auto val : mark) {
        if (val > average)
            cout << val << ' ';
    }
        
    cout << '\n';
    
    
// count the number of marks which is less than 50
    const auto count = std::count_if (begin(mark),end(mark),[](int x){return x<50;});
    cout << "Elements which are <50: " << count << '\n';

    cout << "all integers: ";

//Displaying all the integers in the array.         
    for (const auto val : mark) {
        cout << val << ' ';   
    }

    cout << '\n';
}
```

### result:

(see [in Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/aGnq1vb8K))

```
Average mark: 56.2
Highest mark: 90
Lowest mark: 30

66 90 
Elements which are <50: 2
all integers: 30 50 66 90 45
```

Comment: Also, the fact that `double total;` isn't initialized probably is causing some issues.